# Can rxjs timeout operator trigger a function instead of returning error and cancelling the http call

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs6, angular-http-interceptors, angular-httpclient-interceptors

I'm implementing an angular interceptor service which looks for error and shows a snackbar, now I'm trying to add functionality to handle "No internet" or "Slow Internet". I tried with timeout operator but after the timeout, the HTTP call is canceled but my requirement is to notify the user that their internet is slow and then maybe cancel after some time, so I need the timeout operator to trigger a function rather than triggering an error

This is my code

```
  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    request = request.clone({

      setHeaders: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${this.user.getToken()}`
      }
    });

    return next.handle(request).timeout(8000)
      catchError((error) => {
        console.log(error)
        console.log(error.name)
        if(error.name == 'TimeoutError'){
          this.alert.snack('Your Internet seems to be very slow','OK',4000)
          this.alert.showSlowInternet()

        }
        else if(error.error.detail === "Given token not valid for any token type"){
          this.global.refresh(this.router.url)
        }
        else if(error.error.detail === "No Connectivity"){
          this.alert.dismissableSnack('No Connectivity detected','DISMISS',)
        }
        else if(error.error.detail){
        this.alert.snack(error.error.detail,'OK')
        }

        else{
            this.alert.snack('Server not responding','OK')
        }
          return throwError(error);
      })
  }
```

Comment: If you use latest rxjs library, your `operators` (timeout, catchError) should be wrapped in `pipe` https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-eegqyz?file=index.ts&devtoolsheight=100

Comment: yeah bt it works even if they are chained right and also that was not my question